# What is python list indexes explanation here?

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

Here is part of my code:

```
some_item = target_item
first_item = my_list[0]
print first_item
print some_item
print my_list.index(first_item)
print my_list.index(some_item)
print "Finished"
exit()
```

And here is what I get:

```
<models.adb.ADB object at 0x7f1ec7654b50>
<models.seb.SEB object at 0x7f1ec7654b90>
0
0
Finished
```

My items in `my_list` are class objects.

Could someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: what is the result of `first_item == some_item`?

Comment: Can you show us how you added them to the list?

Comment: and what behaviour do you expect? what have to be explained? Is it true that you assume that `first_item` not equal to `some_item` (as the results of `print`s are different) and thus are surprised by the fact that `.index` returns the same number?

Comment: I think the we might need to see the `__eq__` method defined in `models.seb.SEB`

Comment: `some_item = target_item` and `first_item = my_list[0]`. Both are different objects. What explanation do you want? Probably you forgot to mention the way you initialized `target_item `

Comment: In the future, when asking a question that involves code, be sure to include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- that is, a code sample that includes everything needed for someone else to see the same problem, and nothing additional to that minimum. As it is, you're including insufficient information (there are several different ways this could occur, depending on the definition of classes referenced in your code), so all you're getting is guesses, not definitively guaranteed-correct answers.

Comment: You have given us the actual output, which is good. You have failed to share the expected output so we are left trying to guess what is different between the actual output and the expected output. SO users are no better at mind reading than the average population so you need to actually say things explicitly and not assume we know what is in your head.

Comment: What surprised me was the fact that I have to different objects in the list at different indexes (at least that is my assumption because I do not think that we can have two different objects at same index on the list). But when I call list.index() both of them return 0. It is reasonable for first_item, but I did not expect that for some_item

Comment: Actually you hit the good point. I do have __eq__ implemented and according to my implementation although ADB and SEB are two different object, the first_item==some_item is True.
But still, does it explain the list.index() behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the comparison implemented for `ADB` and `SEB`, probably by implementing the `__eq__` operator for this classes.

When python will look for the instance of `first_item` and `some_item` on the list, he will use this operator to determine if the `i`-th element on the list is this element, sweeping for every `i`.

Therefore, if the implementation is like

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def __eq__(parentObj):
        return self.x == parentObj.x

class ADB (Parent):
   def __init__(self): super.__init__()

class SEB (Parent):
   def __init__(self): super.__init__()
```

it would result in `ADB() == SEB()`, therefore, causing the objects to both "match" the first list's element when being compared to it, but being different objects at the same time.

---

Note that same can go for this as well, used inheritance for simplification of the example.

```
class ADB (Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def __eq__(obj):
        return self.x == obj.x

class SEB (Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def __eq__(obj):
        return self.x == obj.x
```

Comment: I think you are right, yes in my __eq__ they are equal, but I think python matches the addresses of those objects and not calling __eq__

Comment: Actually the main problem was when I tried to call my_list.remove(some_item) it seemed that it does not remove, but when I call my_list.remove(some_item) twice in a row, it removes it, and the strange things is when I call it for third time in a row, it does not throw exception!